# flask-restless restrict RESTfull api access

Tags: python, flask, flask-restless

I only want logged-in users to access my RESTfull API. I have been searching all over and couldn't find any source which tells me how to do it. Weird, because I think it's very common to protect data.

I am using a `Flask` project with `Flask-login` and `flask-Restless`. I CRUD my data through `SQL-alchemy` classes to access my MySQL database. I create my RESTfull api like:

```
api_manager = APIManager(app, flask_sqlalchemy_db=db)
api_manager.create_api(Items, methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PUT'])
```

How should I restrict access to my RESTfull api for users who are not logged in, or can't I do it with flask-restless? If not, what should/could I better use?

I am trying out some techniques, so suggestions in any directions are welcome!

Thanks in advance

---

After some more playing around I have found a solution. It might not be the best but it does the trick without too much code:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    if ('/api/' in str(request.url_rule)) && (not current_user.is_authenticated()):
        return redirect('/login')
```

Is this the right way to go? Adding Preprosessors is a lot of code for every possible HTTP request. https://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customizing.html#request-preprocessors-and-postprocessors

Comment: I am trying to do the exact same thing, if you came up with a better solution I hope you'd share it :)

Comment: there's a hacky way to do it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42533259/python-flask-using-flask-restless-with-flask-httpauth

Comment: nice way as well..

Comment: I deleted my comment, because I saw it was basically the same solution as I mentioned in the update of the question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you achieve what you want by [customizing Flask-Restless](http://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customizing.html). You could use a preprocessor to intercept your API request.

Here is a snippet. Please, be aware that this is an untested snippet.

```
def auth_func(*args, **kw):
    if not current_user.is_authenticated():
        raise ProcessingException(description='Not authenticated!', code=401)

api_manager = APIManager(app, flask_sqlalchemy_db=db)
api_manager.create_api(Items, methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PUT'], preprocessors=dict(POST=[auth_func]))
```

Similarly, you can register the preprocessor to your `APIManager`, enabling it for all API's.

```
api_manager = APIManager(app, flask_sqlalchemy_db=db, preprocessors=dict(POST=[auth_func]))
api_manager.create_api(Items, methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PUT'])
```

Comment: This will work. I just think this could be done better. Why? Now I'd have to add all HTTP methods to the preprosessors and say that the auth_func() should be executed.
'POST', 'GET_SINGLE', 'GET_MANY', 'PATCH_SINGLE' or 'PUT_SINGLE',   'PATCH_MANY' or 'PUT_MANY', 'DELETE_SINGLE'  'DELETE_MANY'
This is a lot of code.

Comment: So why don't you register the preprocessor to your `APIManager` then? When I first wrote my answer, I thought you would like a fine grain control over the API access. I updated my answer with the suggestion.

Comment: It is already much better. I still have to add an user authentication for every HTTP method (see previous comment). I still have the feeling that someone must use too much code for that and I am still looking for a better solution.