# Python / Flask - Using flask_restless with flask_httpauth

Tags: python, flask, flask-restless, flask-httpauth

my objective in this question is to secure my API.

in my application, I'm using Flask and `flask_restless`'s `APIManager` to provide CRUD API to my `Person` object.

code sample:

```
manager = APIManager(app, flask_sqlalchemy_db=db)
manager.create_api(Person, methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'])
```

and also using `flask_httpauth` to protect my other routes like this:

```
@app.route('/auth/get-token')
@auth.login_required
def get_auth_token():
    token = g.user.generate_auth_token()
    return jsonify({'token': token.decode('ascii'), 'fullname': g.user.fullname})
```

I could not figure out how to use `@auth.login_required` with the `apimanager` to not make it respond to anonymous requests, I read in the documentation something about preprocessors but also couldn't find a way to use it with `@auth.login_required` decorator.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like Flask-Restless currently does not officially support attaching view decorators to the routes it manages. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/jfinkels/flask-restless/issues/497) to add this feature, and there is also [another issue](https://github.com/jfinkels/flask-restless/issues/513) specifically requesting support for Flask-HTTPAuth.

There is yet a [third issue](https://github.com/jfinkels/flask-restless/issues/318), in which a user shows the technique to manually inject the decorators after Flask-Restless created its endpoints. The snippet from that user's example that adds a `get_cache` decorator is below:

```
manager = flask.ext.restless.APIManager(app, flask_sqlalchemy_db=db)
manager.create_api(Person, methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'])
manager.create_api(Person2, methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'])

# hackish view decoration:
for model in [Person, Person2]:
    model_route = '{0}api0.{0}api'.format(model.__name__.lower())
    app.view_functions[model_route] = get_cache(app.view_functions[model_route])
```

In your case, you would replace `get_cache` with `auth.login_required`.

Update: As discussed below in the comments, the argument in `'{0}api0.{0}api'` is the table name, so the above code will only work if table names are left for Flask-SQLAlchemy to generate. If the model has a custom table name, then use that instead of `model.__name__.lower()`.

Comment: thanks a lot, I don't want to be annoying but I'm getting this error and can't figure out what went wrong: `app.view_functions[model_route] = auth.login_required(app.view_functions[model_route])
KeyError: 'personapi0.personapi'`

Comment: Woops, I figured it out, apparently flask adds the letter s as a suffix for the class's name, so the registered function for  `Person` API is called `personsapi0.personsapi`, I hope you add this to your answer and thank you so much it did solve the problem.

Comment: it has to be : `model_route = '{0}sapi0.{0}sapi'.format(model.__name__.lower())`

Comment: @MotassemMK could it be because you are using a custom table name with the plural form?

Comment: ops.. yep that's it

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use `Flask-Security`. There is a [tutorial](http://mandarvaze.github.io/2015/01/token-auth-with-flask-security.html) about how to use it to security your API interface.